# Append n number of times in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a jquery plugin

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin= function(opt){
        var defaults = {      
            num : '5';
        };

        return this.each(function(){
            var opt = $.extend(defaults, opt);   
            var template=$('<span class="active">aaaa</span>');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

How can I append the template `num` number of times to `$(this)`. Is there a way other than for loop because I think running for loop for every item on which plugin is applied will create problem and overload the page . Correct me if I'm wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes

1. You will need to use a loop to create the copies of the template
2. You can move the creation of the template outside the `this.each()` loop so that the loop is executed once per the plugin initialization(that is `$('div').myplugin()` will execute the loop only once)
3. Use an array to create the template copies
4. In the `each` loop append the coned copy of the template

Something like this

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        num: 5
    };
    var template = '<span class="active">aaaa</span>';
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (opt) {
        var opt = $.extend(defaults, opt),
            array = [],
            $tmpl;
        for (var i = 0; i < opt.num; i++) {
            array.push(template);
        }
        $tmpl = $(array.join(''));


        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).append($tmpl.clone())
        });


    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/32wr5/)

Comment: Will for loop create a problem if there are 100+ divs ? If you can explain what you did i would b thankful